# How to issue claims (boolean) depending on AD group

Tags: adfs, claims

I've been battling an issue where my application requires the value to be set for a claim to 'true' or 'false'. I am trying to issue a claim based on if the user is in the AD group. If they are, send a true, and if they're not, send a false.

Would this exist in the same ADFS claim?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The following rule issues group claims for a user based on the user's group membership:

```
    c:[Type == "https://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid", Value == "S-1-5-21-397933417-626991126-188441444-512", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]  
=> issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group", Value = "administrators", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, ValueType = c.ValueType);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/technical-reference/when-to-use-a-send-group-membership-as-a-claim-rule

Comment: Thank you for this. Is it possible to send a value in the same claim (like true/false) if the person is in the group?

Comment: This way it would always return a value?

Comment: I think so, given that you can configure MFA settings based on group membership as shown here. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/blob/master/WindowsServerDocs/identity/ad-fs/operations/Configure-Authentication-Policies.md